# Can a decreasing sequence of subharmonic functions converge to a discontinuous function?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

If $u_n:\Bbb C\to \Bbb R$ are subharmonic, bounded, continuous, and $u_{n+1}\le u_n$ for all $n$, can their limit be discontinuous?

By boundedness, it is easy to show that the limit function $u$ will satisfy the submean value property using the MCT or DCT. Proving upper semicontinuity is also simple by just taking a union of open sets for the preimage $\{u<a\}$. Yet I can neither prove that $u$ will be continuous nor find a counterexample.

Intuitively I would be inclined to think that no counterexample can exist, because subharmonic functions are supposed to behave like convex functions. The limit of convex functions is convex, hence continuous, and Dini's theorem proves the result on compact sets. However I have no way of making this rigorous, so I am wondering if this even holds.

Comment: for any proper (not identically $-\infty$) subharmonic function $u$, continuous or not, the functions obtained by integrating it on small discs around any point - normalized as usual by dividing by the area of the circles - are continuous, subharmonic and converge decreasingly to $u$ when the radius goes to zero; iterating the integrals you can get smooth subharmonic functions too with same - the main issue here is that subharmonic functions are only upper continuous but not necessarily continuous; any basic text on subharmonic functions like Rado or Hayman has the details which can be tedious

Comment: @Conrad so that means the statement in my question is false and there is a counterexample?

Comment: Yes - any subharmonic functions is a limit of decreasing continuous subharmonic functions and the proof is as sketched above by taking normalized disc averages since subharmonic functions even if they take $-\infty$ as values like say $\log|f|$ for a holomorphic $f$ with zeroes are still locally integrable unless they are identically $-\infty$. The monographs by Hayman (vol 1) and Rado have more details, but essentially the proof follows from the definition of subharmonicity with integral averages and the usual smoothing properties of integrals.

Comment: @Conrad but my question is not if all subharmonic functions are limits of subharmonic functions. I am asking if a bounded, decreasing sequence of continuous subharmonic functions must converge to a continuous function.

Comment: Pick any subharmonic function that is not continuous ($v(z)=\Sigma{a_n\log |z-\frac{1}{n}|}, a_n>0, a_n \to 0$ fast enough so $v(0)$ finite, hence $v$ discontinuos at $0$, let $u(z)=\exp(v(z))$, and apply the construction sketeched above getting *continuos* subharmonic functions decreasingly convergent to $v$ - note that by the maximum principle any subharmonic function cannot have a maximum on its open domain